# Unable to use(file manipulation) the Pyline --output-format:file

Tags: python, json, pylint

Using pylint in a python script as,

`--output-format=json:report.json`

The warning from Pylint are stored in the report.json file.
But its not possible to read / json.dump the report.json file.

For example, after successfully execute the `Run() from pylint.lint`,
its not possible to do,

```
with open(report.json, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    pylint_data = file.read()
    - or - 
    pylint_data = json.load(file)
```

I presume the Pylint process kept the file busy or not allow to read, but what is the reason?

Ok, as someone asked for a minimal reproducible example, here it is.

```
from pylint.lint import Run
import os
import json

DEFAULT_SCRIPT_DIRECTORIES = ["scripts/"]

PYLINT_JSON_FILE = 'pylint_output.json'
PYLINT_CONFIG = "pylintrc"

cmd = [f'--rcfile={PYLINT_CONFIG}']
cmd += [f'--output-format=json:{PYLINT_JSON_FILE}']

for script_path in DEFAULT_SCRIPT_DIRECTORIES:
    add_path = os.path.abspath(script_path)
    if os.path.isfile(add_path):
        add_path = os.path.dirname(add_path)
    cmd.append(add_path)

pylint_run = Run(cmd, do_exit=False)

if os.path.exists(PYLINT_JSON_FILE):
    with open(PYLINT_JSON_FILE, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        pylint_data = json.load(file)
else:
    print("Failed to create PyLint JSON report.")
```

in the json.load() I'm getting,
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` Error. I've checked manually, the `PYLINT_JSON_FILE` exists with valid data.

Comment: What error are you getting? It'd help to make a [mre] including enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: added a simple example with the question.

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` doesn't really say what the problem is. Please include the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341) or at bare minimum the whole last line.

Comment: Its an error as, 
json.decoder.JSONDecoderError: Expecting Value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
on line `pylint_data = json.load(file)`

Comment: I'm getting "The config file pylintrc doesn't exist!" and no further output. I could create it if necessary, but is it even relevant? Again, [mre].

Comment: Also, what Pylint version are you using? `do_exit` seems to have been deprecated and it seems like it's having no effect for me, but I can't find where it's documented.

Comment: OK, from that error, it sounds like the file's empty. `file.read()` should succeed though, no?

Comment: Pylint 2.15.10.
Any Pylintrc file would do. i.e., https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/main/pylintrc

Comment: No. First file is not empty, as Pylint run successfully (depends on the warning/so). And interesting is file.read() brings nothing (even no error)